# How do I conditionally combine some rows (but not others) in R data frames?

Tags: r, join, dplyr, merge, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out how to merge/join two data frames in such a way that if a certain condition is met, R combines two rows from the two data frames into one row, but if the condition is not met, R adds a new row with NAs in the columns that are not present in the original data frame. I'm unclear if this is a simpler join than I think it is, but I've been unable to figure out how to do this, even after reading through some stack overflow results ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726466/conditional-joining-data-frames-r) or [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618808/how-to-merge-two-dataframes-in-r-conditionally-common-column-condition)).

Below are two example data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name_df1 = c("Alan", "Steve", "Melanie", "Steve", "Melanie"),
                  Date_df1 = c("02/18/2008", "02/18/2008", "03/14/2009", "04/19/2009", "03/16/2009"),
                  Job_df1 = c("Cook", "Security", "Greeter", "Security", "Greeter"),
                  Hours_df1 = c(8.5, 7.0, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0))

df2 <- data.frame(Name_df2 = c("Steve", "Alan", "Melanie", "Melanie", "Steve", "Carter"),
                  Date_df2 = c("02/18/2008", "02/18/2008", "03/14/2009", "03/17/2009","04/25/2009", "08/15/2011"),
                  Job_df2 = c("Police", "Chef", "Greeter", "Greeter", "Security", "Doorman"),
                  Hours_df2 = c(8.5, 7.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.0, 6.5),
                  Wage_df2 = c(80, 77, 127.5, 90, 145, 100))
```

df1 and df2 both describe dates on which certain individuals worked, their job titles, names, and hours worked on the specified date, and *only* df2 also contains wage information. What I want to do is join df1 and df2 into a df3 with the following columns:

- "Name_df1"
- "Name_df2"
- "Date_df1"
- "Date_df2"
- "Job_df1"
- "Job_df2"
- "Hours_df1"
- "Hours_df2"
- "Wage_df2"

Specifically, I want to join df1 and df2 such that for every row in df1 or df2, if there is an exact match for **both** the value in the "Name_df1"/"Name_df2" column and the value in the "Date_df1"/"Date_df2" column in the corresponding column in the opposite data frame (i.e. in df1, if the value in the "Date_df1" column and "Name_df1" columns each have an exact match in the "Date_df2" column and "Name_df2" column, respectively, of df2):

- A row is created in df3 that has the "Name_df1", "Name_df2", "Date_df1", "Date_df2", "Job_df1", "Job_df2", "Hours_df1", "Hours_df2", and "Wage" columns filled in with the relevant values from df1 and df2. The values in the "Job_df1", "Job_df2", "Hours_df1", and "Hours_df2", may or may not be the same.

However, if there is **not** an exact match for **both** the value in the "Name_df1"/"Name_df2" column and the value in the "Date_df1"/"Date_df2" column, then df3 should get a row that includes only the information from df1 in "Name_df1", "Date_df1", "Job_df1", and "Hours_df1", and NAs in "Name_df2", "Date_df2", "Job_df2", "Hours_df2", and "Wage_df2". Or, if the original row is from df2, then df3 should get a row that includes only the information from df2 in "Name_df2", "Date_df2", "Job_df2", "Hours_df2", and "Wage_df2", and NAs in "Name_df1", "Date_df1", "Job_df1", and "Hours_df1".

I know that's a mouthful, but based on the df1 and df2 specified above, this is what df3 would look like:

```
df3 <- data.frame(Name_df1 = c("Alan", "Steve", "Melanie", "Steve", "Melanie", NA, NA, NA),
                  Name_df2 = c("Alan", "Steve", "Melanie", NA, NA, "Melanie", "Steve", "Carter"),
                  Date_df1 = c("02/18/2008", "02/18/2008", "03/14/2009", "04/19/2009", "03/16/2009", NA, NA, NA),
                  Date_df2 = c("02/18/2008", "02/18/2008", "03/14/2009", NA, NA, "03/17/2009", "04/25/2009", "08/15/2011"),
                  Job_df1 = c("Cook", "Security", "Greeter", "Security", "Greeter", NA, NA, NA),
                  Job_df2 = c("Chef", "Police", "Greeter", NA, NA, "Greeter", "Security", "Doorman"),
                  Hours_df1 = c(7.0, 7.0, 6.0, 7.0, 6.0, NA, NA, NA),
                  Hours_df2 = c(7.0, 8.5, 6.0, NA, NA, 7.0, 7.0, 6.5),
                  Wage_df2 = c(77.0, 80, 127.5, NA, NA, 90.0, 145.0, 100))
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: 'How do I conditionally combine some rows (but not others)' You don't. A cross join gives all combinations of a row from each table & then you keep the ones that satisfy a condition. Read about basics of joining.

Comment: I'm aware of cross joins, just unsure of what filtering to these specific conditions would look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for `full_join` but to get the exact desired output (`df3`) you need to perform some manipulation.

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2, by = c('Name_df1' = 'Name_df2', 'Date_df1' = 'Date_df2')) %>%
  mutate(Name_df2 = ifelse(is.na(Job_df2), NA, Name_df1),
         Name_df1 = ifelse(is.na(Job_df1), NA, Name_df1), 
         Date_df2 = ifelse(is.na(Job_df2), NA, Date_df1),
         Date_df1 = ifelse(is.na(Job_df1), NA, Date_df1)) %>%
  select(starts_with('Name'), starts_with('Date'), starts_with('Job'), everything())

#  Name_df1 Name_df2   Date_df1   Date_df2  Job_df1  Job_df2 Hours_df1 Hours_df2 Wage_df2
#1     Alan     Alan 02/18/2008 02/18/2008     Cook     Chef       8.5       7.0     77.0
#2    Steve    Steve 02/18/2008 02/18/2008 Security   Police       7.0       8.5     80.0
#3  Melanie  Melanie 03/14/2009 03/14/2009  Greeter  Greeter       6.0       6.0    127.5
#4    Steve     <NA> 04/19/2009       <NA> Security     <NA>       7.0        NA       NA
#5  Melanie     <NA> 03/16/2009       <NA>  Greeter     <NA>       6.0        NA       NA
#6     <NA>  Melanie       <NA> 03/17/2009     <NA>  Greeter        NA       7.0     90.0
#7     <NA>    Steve       <NA> 04/25/2009     <NA> Security        NA       7.0    145.0
#8     <NA>   Carter       <NA> 08/15/2011     <NA>  Doorman        NA       6.5    100.0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I'm looking for. However, when a name and date pair appear in both df1 and df2, I want the Name_df1 and Name_df2 and Date_df1 and Date_df2 columns to all be populated in df3. So in the result of your code, I would want Name_df2 in row 1 to say "Alan" and Date_df2 in row 1 to say "2/18/2008." The same would apply to rows 2 and 3 (Steve and Melanie on dates 2/18/2008 and 3/14/2009, respectively), because those pairs match in the date and name columns in df1 and df2. Do you know how I could achieve that?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That requires small change in the answer. See my updated answer @ben_p_4370

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Do you know how I can stop ifelse from turning my Dates into numeric (e.g.17266)?

Comment: Instead of `ifelse` use `if_else`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be a way to join those two data frames:

library(dplyr)
df3 <- df1 %>% full_join(df2, by="Name", suffix= c(".df1", ".df2"))

Result:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITPdV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a full join with `keep = TRUE` :

```r
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2, by = c(Name_df1 = "Name_df2", Date_df1 = "Date_df2"), keep = TRUE)
#>   Name_df1   Date_df1  Job_df1 Hours_df1 Name_df2   Date_df2  Job_df2 Hours_df2
#> 1     Alan 02/18/2008     Cook       8.5     Alan 02/18/2008     Chef       7.0
#> 2    Steve 02/18/2008 Security       7.0    Steve 02/18/2008   Police       8.5
#> 3  Melanie 03/14/2009  Greeter       6.0  Melanie 03/14/2009  Greeter       6.0
#> 4    Steve 04/19/2009 Security       7.0     <NA>       <NA>     <NA>        NA
#> 5  Melanie 03/16/2009  Greeter       6.0     <NA>       <NA>     <NA>        NA
#> 6     <NA>       <NA>     <NA>        NA  Melanie 03/17/2009  Greeter       7.0
#> 7     <NA>       <NA>     <NA>        NA    Steve 04/25/2009 Security       7.0
#> 8     <NA>       <NA>     <NA>        NA   Carter 08/15/2011  Doorman       6.5
#>   Wage_df2
#> 1     77.0
#> 2     80.0
#> 3    127.5
#> 4       NA
#> 5       NA
#> 6     90.0
#> 7    145.0
#> 8    100.0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>